# Use CURL with youtube-dl as external downloader

Tags: python-3.x, curl, pythonanywhere, youtube-dl

I am using the youtube-dl library for converting videos to mp3, and looking to speed up the conversion & downloading process.

(Recently read about **--external-downloader** aria2c(to speed downloads) with youtube-dl, and found it super amazing. but since my sites hosted on pythonanywhere, they don't provide access to ROOT(admin) to install these packages).

There are several external-downloaders supported by youtube-dl like **curl,wget,httpie**.

**Since,(I was not able to install aria2c), I decided to try 'curl':**

Here's the code, I have tried for my application:

```
ydl_opts = {
'format': 'worstaudio/worst',
'postprocessors': [{'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
           'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
           'preferredquality': '192'}],
'outtmpl': 'media/'+result,
'noplaylist':True,
'ignoreerrors':True,
'max-downloads':1,
'external-downloader':'curl'
}
ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts)
```

But, that seems nothing has improved, also (I am not able to understand if it is correct or not) (referred the youtube-dl documentation, but didn't find anything helpful with this).

Can anybody help me, where am I going wrong?

Also, is there anything that can be done to boost speed for youtube-dl downloads?

Comment: Just trying to use curl for the main page download, which is blocked for me (429), and apparently it uses external downloader for videos only, as more or less stated in the doc. Trying to see why aiohttp request via the same proxy works and urlopen fails.